# Ensure Posts that Belong to a User are Deleted if that User is Deleted

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've got a phoenix application where posts belong to users.

When I try to delete a user who has posts I'm getting the following error:

```
Ecto.ConstraintError at DELETE /users/2
constraint error when attempting to delete model:

    * foreign_key: posts_user_id_fkey
```

I'm assuming that this error means that it won't delete the user because there are existing posts that belong to that user.

How do I delete the users posts if/when the user is deleted?

Answer (score 5):

I've done some more searching and I think I found the answer to my question:

I've added the following

```
schema "users" do
  ...
  has_many :posts, MyApp.Post, on_delete: :delete_all
  ...
end
```

Please comment if this isn't the right way to do this or if there is a better way.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer. Here you have handy links: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/ https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html